# php display multilevel treenode menu

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, treenode, multi-level

How do I display this structure into a multi-level menu?

Here's the structure:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'product_category_code' => string 'bracelets' (length=9)
      'product_category_desc' => string 'Bracelets' (length=9)
      'parent_node' => string '' (length=0)
      'inactive' => string '0' (length=1)
      'sort' => string '0' (length=1)
      'created_by' => string '1' (length=1)
      'created_date' => string '2014-03-14 22:04:08' (length=19)
      'modified_by' => string '1' (length=1)
      'modified_date' => string '2014-03-14 22:09:05' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array
      'product_category_code' => string 'floral-dress' (length=12)
      'product_category_desc' => string 'Floral Dress' (length=12)
      'parent_node' => string '' (length=0)
      'inactive' => string '0' (length=1)
      'sort' => string '0' (length=1)
      'created_by' => string '1' (length=1)
      'created_date' => string '2014-03-14 22:09:49' (length=19)
      'modified_by' => string '1' (length=1)
      'modified_date' => string '2014-03-30 19:06:58' (length=19)
  2 => 
    array
      'product_category_code' => string 'flowery-bracelets' (length=17)
      'product_category_desc' => string 'Flowery Bracelets' (length=17)
      'parent_node' => string 'bracelets' (length=9)
      'inactive' => string '0' (length=1)
      'sort' => string '0' (length=1)
      'created_by' => string '1' (length=1)
      'created_date' => string '2014-03-14 22:09:16' (length=19)
      'modified_by' => string '1' (length=1)
      'modified_date' => string '2014-03-30 19:08:44' (length=19)
  3 => 
    array
      'product_category_code' => string 'small-flowery-bracelets' (length=23)
      'product_category_desc' => string 'Small Flowery Bracelets' (length=23)
      'parent_node' => string 'flowery-bracelets' (length=17)
      'inactive' => string '0' (length=1)
      'sort' => string '0' (length=1)
      'created_by' => string '1' (length=1)
      'created_date' => string '2014-03-14 22:08:35' (length=19)
      'modified_by' => string '1' (length=1)
      'modified_date' => string '2014-03-30 19:09:44' (length=19)
  4 => 
    array
      'product_category_code' => string 'summer-dress' (length=12)
      'product_category_desc' => string 'Summer Dress' (length=12)
      'parent_node' => string '' (length=0)
      'inactive' => string '0' (length=1)
      'sort' => string '0' (length=1)
      'created_by' => string '1' (length=1)
      'created_date' => string '2014-03-14 22:09:29' (length=19)
      'modified_by' => string '0' (length=1)
      'modified_date' => null
```

And output should be like this:

- Bracelets

  - Flowery Bracelets

    - Small Flowery Bracelets
- Floral Dress
- Summer Dress

Here is what I did but it still display the child nodes a

```
function getChildren($rows, $p = 0) {
$r = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    if ($row['parent_node']==$p) {
        var_dump($p);
        $r[$row['product_category_code']] = getChildren($rows, $row['product_category_code']);
    }
}
return $r;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you still have the categories in the array when you already assigned them. What you can do is to do the function where you pass the argument as a reference, and the in the foreach loop to have the ability to clear the array from that already assigned category. Simple implementation below.

```
function getChildren(&$rows, $p = 0) {
    $r = array();
    foreach($rows as $row_id => $row) {
        if ($row['parent_node']==$p) {
            $r[$row['product_category_code']] = getChildren($rows, $row['product_category_code']);
            unset($rows[$row_id]);
        }
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ailvenge! Exactly what I needed! I notice the "&" on the $rows on the parameter. Could you please explain what is it for?

Comment: You are passing the argument as a reference to the variable in a memory - you can then update the array / delete the rows as you see there. When you delete the &, php will pass the copy of the array instead of the original array, so even when you delete an element, you still delete it from the copy of the array, so it won't have any effect on the original array :)

Comment: Ailvenge, I notice a problem that when record having a parent node comes before is parent, is not being displayed as a child. Given the array above, if Bracelets has a parent node of Floral Dress, Bracelets is not being displayed as a child node.